# How get public ip for kubernetes pod?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

**The question:**
I have a VOIP application running in a kubernetes pod. I need to set in the code the public IP of the host machine on which the pod is running. How can I get this IP via an API call or an environmental variable in kubernetes? (I'm using Google Container Engine if that's relevant.) Thanks a lot!

**Why do I need this?**
The application is a SIP-based VOIP application. When a SIP request comes in and does a handshake, the application needs to send a SIP invite request back out that contains the public IP and port which the remote server must use to set up a RTP connection for the audio part of the call.

**Please note:** 
I'm aware of kubernetes services and the general best-practise of exposing those via a load balancer. However I would like to use hostNetwork=true and expose ports on the host for the remote application to send RTP audio packets (via UDP) directly. This kubernetes issue (https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/23864) contains a discussion of various people running SIP-based VOIP applications on kubernetes and the general concessus is to use hostNetwork=true (primarily for performance and due to limitations of load balancing UDP I believe).

Comment: Hi - as you're new to the community you might want to read the [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) guide to learn how comments and the voting/accepting systems works around here.

Answer (score 1):

You can query the API server for information about the Node running your pod like it's addresses. Since you are using hostNetwork=true the $HOSTNAME environment variable identifies the node already.

There is an example below that was tested on GCE.

The code needs to be run in a pod. You need to install some python dependencies first (in the pod):

```
pip install kubernetes
```

There is more information available at:
https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/client-python

```py
import os
from kubernetes import client, config

config.load_incluster_config()
v1=client.CoreV1Api()
for address in v1.read_node(os.environ['HOSTNAME']).status.addresses:
    if address.type == 'ExternalIP':
        print address.address
```

Comment: Quick follow-up question: I think a good way to get the external ip into my app would be to use an init-container. (see https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/pods/init-container/). What I'm not sure of is whether if you saved the ip address as an environment var in the init container, could the main container then access that?

Comment: Also for anyone reading this: I'm sure this could also be achieved with the go client https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go . The benefit would be you could compile this elsewhere into a single binary and therefore not need python or any other dependencies in the pod.

Comment: Any environment variables set in an init container are lost when that particular container terminates. You could declare a volume and attach it both the init container and your "main" container and persist the external IP in a file there.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that osci, that's what I suspected. I really appreciate your help, thanks again. I'll try the volume approach, or perhaps just run the python code above (or a go version) in the same container as the main voip app.

Comment: @mleonard Did you write a golang program to achieve this ?

Comment: I guess the above python code is out dated